# Oracle - Stored Procedure with same name across multiple schema - Which would be called by default

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, schema

If there is a stored procedure across different schemas (SYS, User defined Schema), which schema would be called by default if we don't mention a Schema Name.

```
**Schema_1**
Sample_SP

**Schema_2**
Sample_SP

**SYS**
Sample_SP

execute Sample_SP
```

Which schema would be executed?

Comment: `select sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) from dual;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on *how* you call the procedure. If you use the simple name (meaning: not prefixed by the schema name), then Oracle will **only** look in the current schema. To call the procedure from any other schema, you must use the qualified name. If you call the procedure using the simple name, and a procedure by that name does not exist in **your** schema, you will get an error - you will not get a "default" place to look in. And, of course, if you use a qualified name to call it from a different schema, but you don't have the required privileges, you will get an error as well.

You may also create a synonym, but that can only be pointed (in the synonym definition) to one of the procedures - in one specific schema.

Comment: You can also read the docs if you want more details. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general008.htm#ADMIN11561

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected as user `schema_1`, then its procedure would be executed.

Others might, or might not ever be executed, depending on whether their owners granted you `execute` privilege on their procedures and whether there are (public or private) synonyms.

But, the bottom line is: first execute your own code, then - if it doesn't exist - search for it elsewhere.

Comment: I believe the question wasn't about finding (and searching), but about defaults. If a user in `schema3` invokes the procedure by name, what will be executed?

Comment: Paragraphs 2 & 3, @mathguy. Maybe some, maybe none - it depends on facts we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It will execute the stored procedure from connected schema.
Stored procedure from SYS will be executed if there is no user defined schema is connected as SYS is default.